# Change enumerate option within newenvironment

Tags: environments, enumerate, class-options

I've been trying to create a new environment to have a sort of recipe or list of steps, like

**Process 1**

Step 1 - Do this;

Setp 2 - Do that;

I'd like it to accept `\label` command since I'll have to reference it.

Based on [wikibooks: LATEX/macros](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros) and [shared latex](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Environments#/Defining_environments_with_parameters), I've been able to produce the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\newcounter{process}[section]
\newenvironment{process}[1][]
{
    \refstepcounter{process}\par\medskip \noindent 
    \textbf{Process~\theprocess #1} \rmfamily  
}
{
    \medskip 
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
This will be my beautiful new environment!
\begin{process}
    \begin{enumerate}[label = \textit{Step \arabic* -}, leftmargin=+.7in]
        \item this is the first step
        \item this is the second step
    \end{enumerate}
    \label{pr:test}
\end{process}
I'm able to reference Process \ref{pr:test}

\end{document}
```

which is quite acceptable. I was wondering if there is better way to do this in which LATEX sets enumerate option in that environment automatically and get rid of

```
[label = \textit{Step \arabic* -}, leftmargin=+.7in]
```

I've been trying to have something like

```
\newenvironment{process}[1][]
{
    \refstepcounter{process}\par\medskip \noindent 
    \textbf{Process~\theprocess #1} \rmfamily  
    \begin{enumerate}[label = \textit{Step \arabic* -}, leftmargin=+.7in]
}
{
    \end{enumerate}
    \medskip 
}
```

which doesn't give the desired results. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define your `process` environment to *include* the `enumerate` setup, you'll lose the capability to properly `\label`-and-`\ref` it, since you'll technically only be able to `\label`-and-`\ref` the `\item`s within your process (not the process itself).

Below I define your `process` environment to take an optional argument using a key-value approach. You can specify a `title` and/or a `label`, which is then inserted at the correct location to properly reference the process.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,xkeyval}

\newcounter{process}[section]

\makeatletter
\define@cmdkey{process}[proc@]{label}[\relax]{}
\define@cmdkey{process}[proc@]{title}[\relax]{}

\newenvironment{process}[1][]
{%
  \setkeys{process}{label,title,#1}%
  \par\medskip\noindent
  \refstepcounter{process}%
  {\bfseries Process~\theprocess{} \proc@title}%
  \ifx\proc@label\relax\else\label{\proc@label}\fi
  \rmfamily
  \begin{enumerate}[label = \textit{Step \arabic* -}, leftmargin=+.7in]
}
{%
  \end{enumerate}
  \addvspace{\medskipamount}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent
This is a process:
\begin{process}[title=Test1,label=pr:test1]
  \item this is the first step
  \item this is the second step
\end{process}
I'm able to reference Process~\ref{pr:test1}. Also see Process~\ref{pr:test2}:
\begin{process}[label=pr:test2]
  \item this is the first step
  \item this is the second step
\end{process}

\end{document}
```

Note that there may occur a page break between your process title and the steps. One could get around this using [`needspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace).